# seperate connected components in ocr in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, ocr

I am doing a project on OCR. Till now, I have been able to do segmentation,feature extraction, character matching and displaying output.
I am using Georgia font.
But for this font 'rt' is getting segmented as a single character instead of two. I used the function: [L Ne]=bwlabel(image);    and I observed that the 'r' and 't' were connected. Is there any way to seperate them?
Thanks

Comment: You could try using [`imerode`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imerode.html), though this might decrease the quality of the characters. Using [`imdilate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html) after segmentation might help restore a little quality, but some details might be permanently lost.